# Deleting .pdb leads recompilation in static library project in 16.9.6

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

*Issue Description*

Deleting .pdb of static library project leads to recompilation in some case in 16.9.6

*Steps to Reproduce*

Compile solution successfully
Delete .pdb file in Debug/Release folder
Press 'Ctrl+Shift+B', it recompiles all CPP files again

*Expected Behavior*

It should re-link again without compiling.

*Actual Behavior*

It re-compiles all CPP files including stdafx.cpp, etc.

I cannot use 16.10 at this moment, do you know which previous version doesn't have this issue?

Comment: Why are you posting a bug report to StackOverflow? StackOverflow is not affiliated with Microsoft or Visual Studio.

Comment: Why are you deleting PDB files anyway?

Comment: @Dai my script cleans the whole content of Debug or Release folder. It worked very well for several years until I upgrade VS to 10.9.6

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall/retry several versions, I figure out that VS2019 **10.9.3** doesn't have this issue.